# Are there any references for the night sky of Toril?

Tags: forgotten-realms

Where can I find details about the constellations and night sky characteristics of Toril? Is this information presented in any of the released books?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing published that I'm aware of. I have a reasonably good knowledge of the Forgotten Realms material presented in Living Forgotten Realms modules, and I don't know of any night sky material there, either.

Candlekeep has an [unofficial article](http://www.candlekeep.com/library/articles/stars.htm) about the subject, which is based on official material. There is also a comprehensive discussion thread [here](http://forum.candlekeep.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=12459), with links to a few visual resources and much discussion of Selune.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have some guess about the reason behind this lack of information ? I had the need for planetary and constellation details for a quest involving time and alignments, but I had to invent everything from scratch, basically.

Comment: I got nothing. The Realms aren't the only setting missing this particular flavor of detail, though. Maybe game designers don't look up much...

Comment: It could be Realmspace, a Spelljammer sourcebook.

Answer (score 10):

In the Forgotten Realms style guide (part of the freely available [DMs Guild Creator Resource - Style Guide Resources](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/267467/DMs-Guild-Creator-Resource--Style-Guide-Resources)), on pages 21 through 25, there is a lot of information on the night sky, including information on the Moon (Selûne), eclipses, the Tears of Selûne (asteroids orbiting Toril), important stars, and constellations.

Comment: An older version of the FR Style Guide can also be found linked from the AL website here: https://adventurersleague.files.wordpress.com/2018/10/1765690-forgotten_realms_style_guide.pdf#page=21